# Let's Encrypt manual certificate with preferred-challenge over DNS

Tags: python, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm trying to generate a letsencrypt certificate for a machine I don't have direct access to (beyond uploading the SSL certificates). I've downloaded the latest CLI (certbot) and discovered a flag `--preferred-challenge` which seems to allow for DNS host verification rather than the standard HTTP verification.

When I run the following:

```
./certbot-auto certonly --manual --preferred-challenge dns --domains domain_to_secure.com
```

I get the following message:

> Self verification requires optional dependency `dnspython` to be installed.

It's easy enough to find the dnspython package on the net, but how do I get certbot to recognize it as a plugin package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `certbot-auto` runs and does all its initial setup, you'll see after the system packages installation a couple lines like:

```
Creating virtual environment...
Installing Python packages...
```

That's your hint. certbot-auto is a polite Python citizen and uses a **virtualenv**. Finding it may be awkward but the location appears fairly standard. Running as root with release v0.9.3, the virtualenv was here for Arch, Centos7 and Ubuntu 16.04: `/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/`. Now that we know that, we can use the virtualenv's `pip` to install the dependency.

`$ /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/pip install dnspython`

---

Bonus if you really want to confirm, mimic certbot's [code](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/blob/v0.9.3/acme/acme/dns_resolver.py#L12):

```
$ /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/python
>>> from acme import util
>>> import acme.dns_resolver
>>> util.activate(acme.dns_resolver.DNS_REQUIREMENT)
```